# React Promise.all challenge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a situation where I make three fetch calls. Every fetch calls has a callback function which will update the respective property of state.twitterfeed object and finally setState. Issue is that it is calling the setState 3 times as of now. My aim is to use  promise.all and update setStatus only once. I tried multiple times but its confusing and challenging.

Code:

```js
this.state = {
  twitterfeed: {
    techcrunch: [],
    laughingsquid: [],
    appdirect: []
  }
}

updateTwitterFeed = (data, user) => {
  const twitterfeed = { ...this.state.twitterfeed
  };
  if (user === "appdirect") {
    twitterfeed.appdirect = data;
  } else if (user === "laughingsquid") {
    twitterfeed.laughingsquid = data;
  } else {
    twitterfeed.techcrunch = data;
  }
  this.setState({
    isloadcomplete: true,
    twitterfeed
  });
};

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(
      "http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=techcrunch"
    )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.updateTwitterFeed(data, "techcrunch"));

  fetch(
      "http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=laughingsquid"
    )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.updateTwitterFeed(data, "laughingsquid"));

  fetch(
      "http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=appdirect"
    )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.updateTwitterFeed(data, "appdirect"));
}
```

Comment: are any of the api dependent on each another response ?

Comment: Can you explain why you only want to call `setState` once? Seems like it would be beneficial to update the page as resources are retrieved.

Comment: All three fetch calls updates the tweets in the 3 columns in the DOM. I want them to update all together instead of one by one when rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the documentation: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

`Promise.all()` actually preserves the order for its returned values.

Hence you could have:

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count =30&screen_name=techcrunch"));
promises.push(fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=laughingsquid"));
promises.push(fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=appdirect"));
// Execute all promises
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log(values);
    const twitterfeed = { ...this.state.twitterfeed};
    twitterfeed.techcrunch = json.parse(values[0]);
    twitterfeed.laughingsquid = json.parse(values[1]);
    twitterfeed.appdirect = json.parse(values[2]);
    this.setState({
        isloadcomplete: true,
        twitterfeed
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the **axios** library.You can use there axios.all([]) calling method. As mentioned in there docs :

```
function A() {
  return axios.get(url,[config]);
}

function B() {
  return axios.get(url,[config]);
}

axios.all([A(), B()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (result_A, result_B) {
    // Both requests are now complete and you can setSate here.
}));
```

Github : https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 1):

```
     var promise1 = fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count =30&screen_name=techcrunch");

     var promise2 = fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=laughingsquid");

     var promise3 =fetch("http://localhost:7890/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=30&screen_name=appdirect");

     Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
        console.log(values);
    });
```

//You can now extend it as you want